# On an application dominated convergence theorem in vN algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

$M$ be a $\mathrm{II}_{1}$ factor equipped with the faithful normal trace $\tau$ in the standard form. Let $\tau(Jx'J\eta)=0,\forall x' \in M'$ and fixed $\eta$ in $L^{1}(M,\tau)$. Is it true $\eta=0$?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Is $M'$ the commutant of $M$? How do you multiply something in the commutant by something in the predual?

Comment: There is no need to use the commutant here.  Your assumptions imply that $x'\mapsto Jx'J$ is an anti-isomorphism between $M'$ and $M$.  Thus your condition is just that $\tau(y\eta)=0$ for all $y\in M$.  This does indeed imply that $\eta=0$, somewhat by definition of what $L^1(M,\tau)$ is, and the extension of $\tau$ to $L^1(M,\tau)$.